# How to pass user input for simple calculator

Tags: javascript

I am self-learning JavaScript and I am a bit confused on how to pass the user input as parameters. I still have the mindset of Python, which is why I think I am struggling. Any help is appreciated.

```js
function userInput(num1, num2) {
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").value);

  return num1, num2;
}



function addition(num1, num2) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (num1 + num2);
  alert("Your answer is " + (num1 + num2));
  return addition;
}
```

```html
<form name="calculator">
  Number 1: <input type="text" id="number1"> Number 2: <input type="text" id="number2">

  <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="javaScript:addition()">
  <input type="button" value="SUB" onclick="javaScript:subtraction()">
  <input type="button" value="MUL" onclick="javaScript:multiply()">
  <input type="button" value="DIV" onclick="javaScript:division()">
  <input type="button" value="MOD" onclick="javaScript:modulus()">

</form>

<p>The result is: <br>
  <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to get the values in `addition` and you don't need `userInput` function. Below is the updated code for you:

```js
function addition() {
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").value);
  var sumOfNumbers = num1 + num2;
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sumOfNumbers;
  alert("Your answer is " + sumOfNumbers);
}
```

```html
<form name="calculator">
  Number 1: <input type="text" id="number1"> Number 2: <input type="text" id="number2">

  <input type="button" value="ADD" onclick="javaScript:addition()">
  <input type="button" value="SUB" onclick="javaScript:subtraction()">
  <input type="button" value="MUL" onclick="javaScript:multiply()">
  <input type="button" value="DIV" onclick="javaScript:division()">
  <input type="button" value="MOD" onclick="javaScript:modulus()">

</form>

<p>The result is: <br>
  <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```

Comment: Ok, I had something like this earlier but then I thought that I would be able to simplify it and pass num1 and num2 into parameters to shorten the code.  So, parameters shouldn't be used at all with this simple code?

Answer (score 1):

Create a button and call the add function

```js
function add(num1, num2) {
  var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value);
  var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").value);
  addition(num1, num2)
  return num1, num2;
}



function addition(num1, num2) {
  document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (num1 + num2);
  alert("Your answer is " + (num1 + num2));
  return addition;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="number1">
<input type="text" id="number2">
<button onclick="add()">Add</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Different way of doing this using event listener. Which is a bit cleaner looking in my opinion. Just giving you another option.

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/py70618w/10/ <--- you can see it live in action.

**HTML**

```
<form name="calculator">
 Number 1: <input type="text" id="number1"> Number 2: <input type="text" 
 id="number2">

 <input type="button" id="add" value="ADD">
 <input type="button" value="SUB" onclick="javaScript:subtraction()">
 <input type="button" value="MUL" onclick="javaScript:multiply()">
 <input type="button" value="DIV" onclick="javaScript:division()">
 <input type="button" value="MOD" onclick="javaScript:modulus()">

</form>

<p>The result is: <br>
 <span id="result"></span>
</p>
```

**Refactored Javascript**:

```
document.getElementById("add").addEventListener("click", function(){
var num1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number1").value);
var num2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("number2").value);
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (num1+num2);
});
```